# Ruby-on-Rails quick search form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following search form:

```
<%= form_tag edit_lot_path(:id), :class => "form-search", method: :get do %>
  <div class="input-append">
    <%= text_field_tag :id, nil, :placeholder => "Lot #", :class => "input-mini search-query" %>
    <%= button_tag(type: "submit", class: "btn") do %>
       <i class="icon-search"></i>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

What I am trying to do is pass a the search field (the id to the path) so the user can do a quick lookup on the id. Unfortunately I get the error `Couldn't find Lot with id=id`.

Please note this is using rails 4.

Comment: what `url` does it go to when u click submit? the form tag does not look right, you are passing `:id` as argument to `edit_lot_path` which generated "lots/id/edit" and `params[:id] = id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For search implementation, ideally you should have separate action e.g. 'search' in your lots controller.

In routes

```
resources :lots do
  get :search, :on => :collection
end
```

In the view file

```
<%= form_tag search_lots_path, :class => "form-search", method: :get do %>
  <div class="input-append">
    <%= text_field_tag :id, nil, :placeholder => "Lot #", :class => "input-mini search-query" %>
    <%= button_tag(type: "submit", class: "btn") do %>
       <i class="icon-search"></i>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

In the lots controller

```
def search
 my_search_string = params['id']
 // YOUR CODE GOES HERE
end
```

Comment: thanks ive implements this as a seperate action and it works!